# Saving image header information to a text file

Tags: python, image, for-loop

I need to extract image header information from multiple JPG files to a text or log file, however when I run the code below I receive an error:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
    for f in filenames:
    print(topdir)
    print(f)
    log = open(topdir + f, 'r')
    data = p.get_json(log)
    formatted_data =(( json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ':')) ))
    print(data)
    print ("There are " + str(len(header_dict)) + " items on the menu.")
```

I get the following error when I run:

```
C:/Users/richie/Desktop/work/imagej/test images and files/XX1
image_D2016-02-03T15-27-56-763207Z_4.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\richie\Desktop\work\header_dir.py", line 25, in <module>
log = open(topdir + f, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    'C:/Users/richie/Desktop/work/imagej/test images and files/XX1image_D2016-02-  03T15-27-56-763207Z_4.jpg'
```

How do I open image files to allow the function in the for loop to run against it?

Comment: log = open(topdir +"/"+ f, 'r')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this code;

```
topdir + f
```

First, you should use `join` on paths, not `+`. The latter doesn't insert the separator between the path and file.
Second, you should join a filename with `root`, not with `topdir`.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
    paths = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]
    for p in paths:
        log = open(p)
        # et cetera
```

Comment: Thanks for that - modified my code, but I get the following error, which I guess is to do with the actual parsing of the image file:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richie\Desktop\work\header_dir.py", line 27, in <module>
    data = p.get_json(log)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_json'

Comment: Sorry - mistake in that last comment - the error I am getting is:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richie\Desktop\work\header_dir.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = x.get_json(log)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexifinfo\pyexifinfo.py", line 44, in get_json
    filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 535, in abspath
    path = _getfullpathname(path)
TypeError: _getfullpathname: illegal type for path parameter

Comment: I printed the the value assigned to log - '<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/richie/Desktop/work/imagej/test images and files/XX1\\image_D2016-02-03T15-27-56-763207Z_4.jpg' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>'.  it looks like the problem is with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import pyexifinfo as x
import json
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def askdirectory():
dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
return dirname

topdir = askdirectory()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
paths = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]
for p in paths:
    data = x.get_csv(p)
    print(p)
    print(data)
    formatted_data =((json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ':')) ))
    f = open('Xheader_info_XML.txt','a')
    f.write(p)

    f.write(formatted_data)

f.close()
```